# Can I replace my broken GFCI outlet with a single outlet with 2 USB ports?

Tags: electrical, switch

The new switch does have 2 backstab holes on each the load and the neutral side, but something tells me hooking both black to one side and both white to the other is not advisable. That would be great if that would be OK...

Also currently, when I check for power with a multimeter at the bottom, hot and neutral have power. At the top, however, I have none. I've screwed with the reset button, which seems shady, maybe broken.  I'm going to assume that's the problem.

Comment: Can you post a photo of this mess?

Answer (score 5):

### This GFCI probably has downstream outlets.

They probably *were* protected by the GFCI, up until the point the GFCI blew.  They will now be dead.

If any of them are in a garage, basement, laundry room, or pretty much any room containing a sink, those outlets need to still be GFCI.   So you will need to provide for their protection.

**You can't defeat the GFCI** ...probably.  As said, you can't break GFCI protection for any outlet that needs to be protected.

### No such thing as a GFCI USB ... Yet.

The market doesn't appear to make what you want, a GFCI receptacle with a USB outlet also.   I could be wrong, if you've found one, carry on.   In the meantime, I'll talk about the workarounds in case you can't find one.

### Install the GFCI protection *upstream*.

Follow the circuit in the other direction, back toward the circuit breaker.  These are outlets that are still working... but lose power when you turn off the breaker for this circuit.  Are there GFCI receptacles in any of those?  Is the breaker itself a GFCI?  Then you're all set.  If it's not that way, buy a GFCI outlet or breaker and  ***make it so***.

You only need one GFCI and it will protect all the outlets downstream of it, provided those are connected to the LOAD side of the GFCI.  Some people daisy-chain GFCI's, that is redundant.

Now you can install your USB outlet (which does not have GFCI).

If you can't do the above, then replace the GFCI the way you found it, and put the USB outlet somewhere else.